# Finding integrating factor $μ(x, y) = x^αy^{\beta}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

İnformation
Suppose a, b, c, and d are constants such that$ ad − bc ≠ 0$, and let m and n be arbitrary real
numbers. Show that

$x\left(cx^m+dy^n\right)dy+(ayx^m+by^{n+1})dx=0$    has an integrating factor $μ(x, y) = x^αy^{\beta}$

I have tried expanding by $ x^αy^{\beta}$ but couldn't get anything

Comment: Do you know what "integrating factor" means, in this context?

Comment: $μ(x, y) = x^αy^{\beta}$ is the integrating factor to make this equation exact

Comment: OK, and do you know what it means for the equation to be exact? If you do, you should be able to multiply through by $x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$ and then write down the equations for the resulting equation to be exact, and then solve those equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: ı did some simplyfying and solved the equations thanks

Comment: Good! Let me encourage you to write up what you found, and to post it as an answer.